# setParameter issue with createNativeQuery of entityManager JPA

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-entitymanager

I want to apply parameter binding to the dynamic native query where the column name which i am fetching i will be passing that dynamically from the UI.(say emp_id in this case).

Following is the sample java code snippet,

```
org.hibernate.Query queryMain;
String fetchColumn="emp_id";
String query;
query="select e.:id from Employee e";
queryMain = (org.hibernate.Query) em.createNativeQuery(query).unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class);
queryMain.setParameter("id", fetchColumn);
```

But when i execute this code i am getting sql syntax error exception. When i print the sql query i am getting as follows

```
select 'emp_id' from Employee
```

Since the column was set in string literals it is throwing the sql syntax exception. Can someone help me on this please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This syntax is used to bind parameters, not column names. If your column name is dynamic, I think you need to build it using a StringBuilder (or something else, taking care of SQL injection)

Comment: @HBo yes thanks for your reply, in my case table name is also dynamic and i got same string literal for table name also, so how to deal that one?

Comment: Unless there's a better solution I don't know of, you need to do it yourself. I'll draft a small example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I told you in my comment, the whole point of `setParameter` is to bind parameter values and prevent SQL injection. You can't use it to pass litterals because they will be surrounded with quotes.
To build a query dynamically, you can do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String fetchColumn = "emp_id"; //take care of SQL injection if necessary
String tableName = Employee.class.getSimpleClassName();
sb.append("select ").append(fetchColumn)
    .append("from ").append(tableName);
String query = sb.toString();
// rest of your code here
```

Comment: the fetchColumn variable will be getting dynamically from UI so instead of "mp_id" if the user sends "emp_id, emp_addr" it will fetch the address column also hence sql injection may happen right?

Comment: Absolutely. If you don't control the string's value, you need to make sure that nothing can happen -> escape every special char, a 'classic' way

Comment: Thanks a lot for your technical support.

Comment: Always a pleasure :)